# Ошибка при подключении и получении ответа из Java

Tags: java, веб-программирование, https

При подключении и отправке данных в параметрах при запросе выходит ошибка, хотя все пути правильные, ключ доступен, адрес правильный, доступ есть.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested targe

```
public static String TransHttpsAuth(String server, String param, String jksPath, String jksPass)
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12"); //jks
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", jksPath);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", jksPass);
        SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        URL url = new URL(server+"/?"+ param);
        System.out.println(" URL + " + url);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();//proxy

        conn.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslsocketfactory);
        InputStream inputstream = conn.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);

        String string = null;
        while ((string = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += string + "\n";
        }

return result; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Сервер, к которому вы подключаетесь, не относится к числу доверенных на вашей системе. Необходимо его сертификат добавить в своё хранилище. Подробности в блоге:  [No more 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target).